# Model predict with zero accuracy after reloading trained model in fresh session

Tags: python-3.x, keras

When i am reloading the trained model I get prediction like untrained model I am unable to resolve this issue.I use pickle file to store weight and also I try to save model architecture and its weight in json and yaml file format but it did  not resolve my issue.After just training I get good result but after refreshing the session when I load pre trained model I get result like model is not trained. Can anyone help me? I am very thankful If someone solve my problem.

```
inp=Input(shape=(None, no_enc_token))
x=SpatialDropout1D(0.2)(inp)
x=LSTM(64, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(x)
out=Dense(6, activation="softmax")(x)
model=Model(inp,out)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100)
model.save("model.h5")  
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("model.h5")
pred=model.predict(test)
out=np.argmax(pred[0, -1, :])
```

Comment: Can you writedown how you are reloading and predicting?

Comment: Yes Sure I will update